# How to add text qualifiers to a PowerShell CSV export?

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

Is there a way to include text qualifiers i.e. `"Column 1"|"Column 2"` when using PowerShell to export to a csv file?

In the script below I remove the text qualifiers that were already transferred in the file because the first column didn't have any for some odd reason.

```
Get-MsolUser -all | 
Where-Object {($_.IsLicensed -eq "True") -and ($_.Title -notlike "Volunteer") } | 
Select-Object Firstname, LastName, Department, Title | 
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "|"| 
% { $_ -replace '","', "|"} | % { $_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file "$path\$file_name" -fo -en ascii
```

Comment: You need to add them, but you had to remove them because they were there? What?  Can l get some examples of the input,  the output you get and the output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with text qualifiers missing in the first column first occurred 'before' I specified the -delimiter parameter, my code above is a bit of a fix and mashup of two methods of fixing that issue, and a bit redundant.

I'm able to generate the intended results with the script below:

```
    $MyData = import-csv \\TestPath\licenses_v2.csv -delimiter '|' | 
    select-object FirstName,LastName,Department,Title,@{expression={'Office 365 AD'}};
    Write-DbaDataTable -sqlinstance $server -database $database -table $table -inputobject $MyData -KeepNulls;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the output may be as you expect but you may be viewing the output file in Excel rather than with a text editor (I used Notepad++).  When I tried to reproduce this I used the following code and viewed the output file in a text editor and each column and row of the output has text qualifiers as expected.  However, when viewing the same file in Excel the first column is displayed by Excel as if it does not have text qualifiers.  Here's the code I ran to test:

```
"[a known UPN from my tenant]","[a known UPN from my tenant]"| 
foreach-object {Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_} | 
Where-Object {($_.IsLicensed -eq "True") -and ($_.Title -notlike "Volunteer")} | 
Select-Object Firstname, LastName, Department, Title | 
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "|" | 
out-file $path\$file_name" -fo -en ascii
```

Comment: When i use this for some reason i get odd errors because it appears every column has text qualifiers except the first one.

Comment: Do you happen to be using Excel in your process somewhere?  If so, I suspect it is actually the culprit that is removing the qualifiers unexpectedly.  I happened across this the other day and learned several things related to this topic:  https://donatstudios.com/Falsehoods-Programmers-Believe-About-CSVs

Comment: Great article, thank you for that, that was my misassumption, I thought since the file came with delimiters embedded once exported, they didn't need to be specified and that the delimiter had nothing to do with the text qualifiers, but that wasn't the case. The delimiter has to be specified or else you will have unexpected behavior with the text qualifiers it appears.